# Having trouble removing a character from a list in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array list, which came from this piece of code:

```
submission = []

for ele in regressor.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test, shuffle=False, batch_size=32)):
  submission.append(np.expm1(np.array(ele['predictions'])))

print(type(submission))

>>> <class 'list'>
```

When I print the list I get this:

```
[array([105527.99], dtype=float32), array([5416.8794], dtype=float32), array([174877.2], dtype=float32)]
```

I would like to remove the brackets and get a clean output.  So, I tried several attempts to replace or pop them out in a loop, but getting errors.

```
for a in submission:
  submission.append(a.pop(-1)) 
  # sub = a.replace("[", "")
  # submission = sub.replace("]","")
  print(submission)
  break
```

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Please help to remove the brackets so I can get a clean output as 105527.99, for example, instead what I am getting now without the clean-up: [105527.99].

Comment: Instead of popping, and appending, you can simply print `a[0]` if you're certain that each array only contains a single element.

Comment: `submission = [a[0] for a in submission]`

Comment: Nice and clean; that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to fiddle with a display string, try to understand what is being displayed. In Python the display usually has some valuable clues to as to the contents.

What you have is a list of numpy array objects, each with 1 element (shape (1,)):

```
In [224]: alist=[np.array([105527.99], dtype=np.float32), np.array([5416.8794], dtype=np.float32)]     
In [225]: alist                                                                                        
Out[225]: [array([105527.99], dtype=float32), array([5416.8794], dtype=float32)]
```

If we 'wrap' the list in `np.array`, we get a (n,1) shape array.  Note its display:

```
In [226]: np.array(alist)                                                                              
Out[226]: 
array([[105527.99  ],
       [  5416.8794]], dtype=float32)
```

Another way of turning such a list into one array is to concatenate them (`hstack` does this nicely):

```
In [227]: np.hstack(alist)                                                                             
Out[227]: array([105527.99  ,   5416.8794], dtype=float32)
```

This is a 1d array, shape (n,).  `tolist` can be used to turn it into a list:

```
In [228]: np.hstack(alist).tolist()                                                                    
Out[228]: [105527.9921875, 5416.87939453125]
```

The other answers take the number out of each component array:

```
In [230]: [i.item() for i in alist]                                                                    
Out[230]: [105527.9921875, 5416.87939453125]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're confusing the object with its string representation. Try the following:

```py
for a in submission:
  out = str(a)
  out = out.replace("[", "")
  out = out .replace("]","")
  print(out)
```

Or alternatively, if you're certain that you only have one element:

```py
for a in submission:
  print(a[0])
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you would bother fiddling with the print-out if you're gonna load it into a dataframe anyway. You could just use your original list and the result would be the same w.r.t. the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the first index will do the job.

```
for a in submission:
    print(a[0])
```